# Is "during the middle of" proper English?

Tags: phrases, expressions

In [this question on the Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44151/what-changes-to-mockingjay-part-2-were-made-due-to-p-s-hoffmans-passing) the question starts with the following observation:

> Actor Philip Seymour Hoffman, who portrayed a character in The Hunger
>   Games, passed away **during the middle of** filming for the Mockingjay
>   movies.

I am not a native speaker, but to me this sounds incorrect. It looks like a combination of "during filming" and "in the middle of filming" (and even "during filming" doesn't feel right).

Comment: "In the middle of" does seem to be much more frequent according to the Google Ngram viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during+the+middle+of%2C+in+the+middle+of%2C+&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20middle%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20middle%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You have a good feel for the language. It sounds _slightly_ off to me (though 'during filming' sounds fine), but I'd say it's acceptable. There are many Google hits for "during the middle of"; it's really a colloquial shortening of 'during the middle section / portion etc', and used here as part of the even longer 'at some time during the middle part of the filming'. Although 'during'  normally refers to durative rather than punctive events, it's not unacceptable here. English is often not well-behaved; compare 'This glass is very full'.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit sloppy, if you think about it, but in common speech the meaning is quite clear, and most listeners wouldn't get distracted by it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of getting the message across, I don't see any problem using *during the middle of* in the sentence. However, it would be more idiomatic to use *during the course of* or *during the process of* as the below Ngram Viewer shows:

[image]

When you put *during the middle of filming*, there is no result in Ngram Viewer as follows:

Edit: As suggested by the below comment, *in the process of filming* and *in the course of filming* seem to be more broadly used than *during*.

[image]

Comment: And "in the course of" and "in the process of" are more frequent than "during the course of" and "during the process of."

Comment: But 'during the middle of' further suggests 'on day 35 (rather than 2 or 61) out of 64' say.